# Creating new variables for each x > 0 in a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, variables

Ok, I fell into the XY trap. Sorry for that.
I'll rewrite my prblem:

I have a list of numbers, eg. l = [1,3,5,1,0,0,0]

I need a string containing the number for each number > 0. Let's say the string is

```
string = "Your number is %s" % (x)
```

How can I get this to work? Especially if there is two times the same number?

~~~~~~~~~~

Old Text:

I need some help here: I have a list, for example

```
numbers = [1,5,3,0,0,0,0]
```

Now I want to define a new variable for each of the numbers that is larger than zero and assign the number to it. For example I take the list above and end up with the variables:

```
o = 1
p = 5
q = 3
```

Also, what is important, if two numbers are the same, I still need one new variable for each of them, while those variable will have the same value.

So if my list was:

```
numbers = [1,5,3,1,0,0,0]
```

I need new variables like this:

```
o = 1
p = 5
q = 3
r = 1
```

Therefore I made the following function:

```
def check(LIST):
    for x in LIST:
        if x > 0:
            #from here on I need help
```

I hope it became clear what I mean and that someone can help :)

Greetings

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I suspect you don't actually need new variables for every non-zero entry. When you have some potentially huge number of things to keep track of, you want a data-structure of some sort. In this case `[x for x in LIST if x > 0]` might suit your needs.

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html

Comment: See also http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html for why this is stupid and what you should be doing instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = [1,5,3,1,0,0,0]
o = ord("o")
from itertools import count
for i,val in zip(count(o),(n for n in numbers if n > 0)):
    globals()[chr(i)] = val

print o
print p
```

but I suspect, as mentioned in the comments, that you **really dont** want to do this

based on your updated question

```
 print "\n".join(["your number is %s"%x for x in set(y for y in numbers if y > 0)])
```